# How do I get my program to recognize and sort the different variable types from a .txt file?

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

Fairly new to C++ (and programming in general). I'm trying to write out a program that would read the following input.txt:

```
10
4
6
A 15 6
B 20 10
B 12 8
A 54 12
B 64 9
A 73 30
A 80 10
B 99 15
```

As shown, there's a combination of int variables as well as char (A and B). Using ifstream, the program recognizes the first three int (10, 4, 6) perfectly fine. However, I'm trying to figure out a way for it to sort out the remaining variables into specific arrays.

For instance, I want it to recognize that every time there's an 'A', the first int after that 'A' goes into one array and the following int goes into another array. So in this case we would have the arrays [15,54,73,80] and [6,12,30,10].

Please note that the input.txt is not set and I need to be able to have it read the file with different number of A's and B's.

Comment: Why not use a std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>? (I am sorry, I don't have time to write out a full answer, but you should probably look into something in the standard library called std::map)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and no worries. I'm doing this for a project and the professor never mentioned std::map, so I don't think I need to use that. Is there a way to use a for or while to to have it run through the entire txt file?

Comment: Read 'A' and compare it against its Ascii value (65). Similarly for B or any alphabet. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Sorta tired, but http://ideone.com/TS1AVr exemplifies the solution. std::map is the simplest way to solve this problem.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. So I can code something that would recognize the Ascii value of each 'A' and input the following two integers into the respective array?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ Don't really remember c++ but I think this might help you. You might use get method to search through the whole text file. Whenever you find A, just use some variable to save next number and the one after it to arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this problem, including writing a boost::spirit grammar, but I wouldn't recommend that to someone new to C++.

Instead, I'll suggest the direct approach, which involves an if statement:

```
- instead of streaming into an int, stream into a string.
- for each string (word), check if word is A or B,  if so add to your char container.  otherwise call stoi and add to your int container.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestion! However, this is for a school project and I don't think I'm allowed to use either std::stoi or boost::spirit grammar. Several options I'm considering is having the program compare the ascii value (as suggested above)  to search for every 'A' and 'B'. 

One other suggestion was the get method, but I'm not too familiar with that.

What do you think?

Comment: Given that std::stoi is part of the c++ standard, I would be very suprised if you are not allowed to use it.  I wouldn't recommend spirit because using it require at least intermediate c++ knowledge.  Did the professor give specific constaints as to what you can and cannot use?    Compariing ascii values would work for the cases you handle (probably basic ascii), but it c-style programming,  and will fail in other locale's.

Comment: After re-reading your problem, I realized you only need to detect the characters A or B, otherweise you have an int.  This greatly simplifies the problem, so I have udpated my answer.  If you have constraints on what parts of C++ you are allowed to use, you need to add this to the question.

Comment: Even if std::stoi is a standard, I have not yet learned about it so I don't think we're allowed to use it. I'm pretty certain we learned the basics necessary to figure out this problem. We've recently learned about structs, and classes, but I don't think that will help for this. On a side note, would it be easier to have it recognize 'A' and just put both numbers after the character into one array? I was thinking from there, I can just sort the numbers myself into separate arrays using for loops and the modulo operator. Again, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have written example quite fast so there can be parts which could be done better, for example checking if string is number, or too much vectors used etd ..

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>

struct Data
{
    std::string key;
    std::vector< int > v;
};

bool isNumber( const std::string& s )
{
    if( s.empty() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    std::locale loc;
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while( it != s.end() )
    {
        if( !std::isdigit( *it, loc) )
        {
            return false;
        }
        ++it;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open( "/home/rwadowski/file.txt" );
    std::map< std::string, Data > map;
    if( file.is_open() )
    {
        std::string line;
        while( std::getline( file, line ) )
        {
            std::istringstream stream( line );
            std::istream_iterator< std::string > it( stream );
            std::istream_iterator< std::string > end;
            std::vector< std::string > strings;
            while( it != end )
            {
                strings.push_back( *it );
                ++it;
            }
            std::string key;
            std::vector< int > v;
            for( const std::string& s : strings )
            {
                if( isNumber( s ) )
                {
                    v.push_back( std::stoi( s ) );
                }
                else
                {
                    key = s;
                }
            }
            Data data = map[ key ];
            data.v.insert( data.v.end(), v.begin(), v.end() );
            map[ key ] = data;
        }
        file.close();
    }

    std::map< std::string, Data >::iterator i = map.begin();
    while( i != map.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Key[" << i->first << "] = ";
        for( int j = 0; j < i->second.v.size(); ++j )
        {
            std::cout << i->second.v[ j ] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to read `input.txt` (`C++`)

```
std::ifstream file("input.txt");
if (!file.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Error\n";
    return 1;
}
int m, n, o, p, q;
char r;
std::vector<int> a, b;
std::vector<char> c;
file >> m >> n >> o;
while (file >> r >> p >> q) {
    if (r == 'A') {
        a.push_back(p);
        b.push_back(q);
        c.push_back(r);
    }
}
file.close();
```

Comment: That works for the concrete example, but does not work for the problem as stated, which is to parse arbitrarty ints and strings as ints or strings.